# How to populate the combobox by keeping the details in properties file

Tags: java, arrays, swing, properties-file

How to populate the combobox by keeping the details in properties file..very much confused

```
static void config(String component, String environment) {     //Function for config file

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {



        input = new FileInputStream("C://Users//");
        prop.load(input);                                  // load a properties file
        Set<Object> keys = prop.keySet();
        String    key;
        Iterator<Object> iter = keys.iterator();


        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            key = (String) iter.next();

            System.out.println("Key: " + key);

            if (key.equals(component + "." + "basefilename")) 
            {
                filename = prop.getProperty(key);
            }

            if (key.startsWith(component + "." + environment + "." + "url"))
            {
                urls.add(prop.getProperty(key));
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Config Values");
        System.out.println("     Filename:" + filename);
        System.out.println("  URL's   :" +    urls.toString());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 

}

static Hashtable<String, String> Validation() {   //function for UI    details

    {
        Hashtable<String, String> logininformation = new    Hashtable<String, String>();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));   //UI Creation
        JPanel label = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        label.add(new JLabel("User", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        label.add(new JLabel("Password", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        label.add(new JLabel("Component", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        label.add(new JLabel("Environment", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        controls.add(username);
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        controls.add(password);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ***String[] Componentstrings = { "dog", "lion", "tiger",    "elephant", };                //components
        String[]    Environmentstrings = { "Produktiv", "prelife","};     //environments
        ***these contents to be in properties file and to be    populated during execution**
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        JComboBox componentList = new JComboBox(Componentstrings);   //combo box for components
        controls.add(componentList);
        panel.add(controls,    BorderLayout.CENTER);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        JComboBox EnvironmentList = new    JComboBox(Environmentstrings);   //combo box for environments
        controls.add(EnvironmentList);
        panel.add(controls,    BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Component frame1 = null;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame1,    panel, "login", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        logininformation.put("user", username.getText());
        logininformation.put("pass", new String(password.getPassword()));
        logininformation.put("component", (String)    componentList.getSelectedItem());
        logininformation.put("environment", (String)    EnvironmentList.getSelectedItem());

        System.out.println("UI values:" + logininformation);

        return logininformation;

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a ">" on each line. Just select your code and then use the `{}` button to keep the formatting of your posted code.

Comment: You just iterate through the properties file and then use the `JComboBox.addItem(...)` method for each property you find.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a [`ComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) that uses the `Properties` as its data container.

### EDIT

Try something like this:

```
public class PropertyComboModel extends AbstractListModel<Object>
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID    = -4409288126984703346L;
  private Properties            data;
  public void setData(Properties data)
  {
    this.data = data;
  }
  public Properties getData()
  {
    return data;
  }
  @Override
  public int getSize()
  {
    return data.size();
  }
  @Override
  public Object getElementAt(int index)
  {
    final Enumeration<Object> e = data.keys();
    for (int i = index; i > 0; --i)
      e.nextElement();
    return (Object) e.nextElement();
  }
}
```

Comment: may I ask how to do it